# Identity for reducing the power in the parameters of Hypergeometric functions

Tags: calculus, special-functions, transformation

Is there any identity/formula for reducing/increasing the power in the parameters of the Gauss Hypergeometric function $ _2F_1(a,b;c;z^d)$ (d is a real) let's say to z?

Is there also any identity for doing the same for the Kummer Confluent Hypergeometric function $ _1F_1(a;c;z^d)$?

In addition, is there any identity connecting both functions without including integrals?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 10 years later and this still is a good question...